# java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.luichi.ygj.a.cf; no empty constructor

Tags: android

When I use the confusion , application wrong 
logs：

> [2016-08-22 11:15:24.343]----->11java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class
>   com.luichi.ygj.a.cf; no empty constructor

[image]

Comment: please paste your code what you have tried. or Please also check your manifest file

Comment: but i have no this class

Comment: what is your app package name?

Comment: then com.luichi.ygj package name and you are using "a" activity in your app. Plz chk it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using ProGuard to obfuscate your code, and another code that uses Java reflection to instantiate classes.

You need to add [`-keep`](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions) rules to your ProGuard configuration file to not obfuscate those classes that are used via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty constructor to the class at `com.luichi.ygj.a.cf`. For example:

```
public class BasicClass {
    public BasicClass(/*This is empty*/) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Empty constructor");
    }

    private void myMethod() {}
}
```

Comment: but i have no this class